# Sorting YouTube data with JSON in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, youtube-data-api

I am working with YouTube Data API and fetching data using JSON Retrofit in RecyclerView. The data consists of list of videos from a channel which also includes live videos.

The URL for the channel is:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCJekW1Vj5fCVEGdye_mBN6Q&maxResults=50&order=date&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]` .

I am trying to sort the data in RecyclerView in such a way that the live videos comes at the top of list and rest of the videos are sorted according to the date. The adapter for RecyclerView is as follows:

```
public class AdapterHome extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<VideoYT> videoList;

    public
    AdapterHome(Context context, List<VideoYT> videoList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.videoList = videoList;
    }

    class YoutubeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView judul, tanggal;

        public YoutubeHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_thumbnail);
            judul = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_judul);
            tanggal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_tglUpdate);
        }

        public void setData(final VideoYT data) {
            final String getJudul = data.getSnippet().getTitle();
            String getTgl = data.getSnippet().getPublishedAt();
            String getThumb = data.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl();

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, YTPlayerActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("video_id", data.getId().getVideoId());
                    i.putExtra("video_title", getJudul);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            judul.setText(getJudul);
            tanggal.setText(getTgl);
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(getThumb)
                   // .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_gujrati)
                    .fit()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(thumbnail, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Thumbnail berhasil ditampilkan");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Thumbnail error: ", e);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_home, parent, false);
        return new YoutubeHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        VideoYT videoYT = videoList.get(position);
        YoutubeHolder yth = (YoutubeHolder) holder;
        yth.setData(videoYT);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return videoList.size();
    }
}
```

The default sorting order doesn't provide any option for this. *Can somebody guide me is it possible or not?*

The JSON data format for this search is as follows:

```
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "BARItyEvlwxiMQCYVni5-wa94N0",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "C51KWXknpd8"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-10-23T11:33:46Z",
        "channelId": "UCJekW1Vj5fCVEGdye_mBN6Q",
        "title": "SAMAA News Live | Samaa TV Live | 24/7 Pakistan News Live Headlines, Bulletins &amp; Press Conferences",
        "description": "samaalive #pakistannewslive #livenews LIVE STREAM SAMAA TV 24/7 | live streaming on YouTube | Headlines , Bulletins, Special & Exclusive Coverage Stay ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/C51KWXknpd8/default_live.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/C51KWXknpd8/mqdefault_live.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/C51KWXknpd8/hqdefault_live.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "SAMAA TV",
        **"liveBroadcastContent": "live",**
        "publishTime": "2020-10-23T11:33:46Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "3qQo96hAKuvzR1yqmOX2RRwm0fg",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "JSUmX2wgwwk"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-10-23T11:20:53Z",
        "channelId": "UCJekW1Vj5fCVEGdye_mBN6Q",
        "title": "Samaa Headlines 4pm | Muhammad Zubair Jhoot bolne ke mahir hain - Shibili Faraz",
        "description": "samaanewslive #breakingnews #pakistannewslive Stay up-to-date on the major news making headlines across Pakistan on SAMAA TV's top of the hour ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JSUmX2wgwwk/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JSUmX2wgwwk/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JSUmX2wgwwk/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "SAMAA TV",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-10-23T11:20:53Z"
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue boils down to having a custom comparator for the `VideoYT` class (defined, for example, within the class `AdapterHome` itself):

```
public static Comparator<VideoYT> myComparator = 
    new Comparator<VideoYT>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(VideoYT a, VideoYT b) {
            boolean aLive = a.getSnippet().getLiveBroadcastContent() == "live";
            boolean bLive = b.getSnippet().getLiveBroadcastContent() == "live";
            if (aLive == bLive)
               return b.getSnippet().getPublishedAt().compareTo(
                      a.getSnippet().getPublishedAt());
            else
               return aLive ? -1 : +1;
        }
    };
```

Then using this comparator for sorting `videoList` in the constructor of `AdapterHome`:

```
public
AdapterHome(Context context, List<VideoYT> videoList) {
    this.context = context;
    Collections.sort(videoList, myComparator);         
    this.videoList = videoList;
}
```

Depending on a wider context of your program (which your sample code above doesn't show), you may also need (want?) to have `videoList` not modified within that constructor. Then, instead of sorting the `videoList` itself, make a copy of it and sort that copy:

```
public
AdapterHome(Context context, List<VideoYT> videoList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.videoList = new ArrayList<>(videoList);
    Collections.sort(this.videoList, myComparator);
}
```

Comment: can you please explain where to add the last part (collection.sort) in the adapter?

Comment: Already said that: in the constructor of the class `AdapterHome`. See my edited answer above.

Comment: thankyou..but it is not displaying anything now. blank screen no items

Comment: Which of the two alternatives you've chosen?

Comment: second one. Let me try with 1st one also

Comment: Showing the list with 1st method but not the live video on top

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223534/discussion-between-summyia-haris-and-stvar).

Comment: @summyia haris: See my updated answer above and the comments within the chat room that provide explanations .